# css - create empty box for text next to text inside paragraph

Tags: html, css

I have these classes:

```
.p_box {
    position: relative;
}

.p_box span {
    background-color: white;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
.p_box:after {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

But it does not really work. I used similar styling for this: `text _____` and it worked. But for box, it does not look the way I need.

I need it to look like this (imagine that it is empty box with borders):

```
some text: |---------|
           |---------|
```

Here you can see how it looks like using that styling: https://jsfiddle.net/envLpanh/

As you can see in example, upper line of the border is hidden where text is, but lower one is not. Also in my application it looks a bit different than in jsfiddle. Both upper and lower borders are hidden where text is, but left border is empty and it looks something like this:

```
some text: -------|
           -------|
```

P.S. I guess it looks that way because it just hides part of the box and then it looks like left border disappeared. So maybe there is some better approach for that.

**Update**

To better understand what I need, look at this picture:

[image]

So that empty box should appear something like this:

`<p class="p_box">Test:</p>` And then after word `Test`, empty box would appear.

**Update2**

Using `left: fixed px number;` is not fully working solution, because it always uses fixed left position and if text differs on each case, it will look messy. Like in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/envLpanh/8/

Comment: Are you trying to get something like this?: https://jsfiddle.net/envLpanh/3/

Comment: So whats the question?

Comment: what exactly is your question? @Andrius

Comment: I updated question with picture example. Maybe that will make it more clear what I am asking.

Comment: Are you trying for this? https://jsfiddle.net/envLpanh/9/ @Andrius

Comment: @ANRUpgradedVersion well in you example, box just goes on top of text. But yeah, whole box should be visible but should go next to text, not on top of it.

Comment: oh i didnt Update my fiddle check this one https://jsfiddle.net/envLpanh/14/ @Andrius

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made the below changes in CSS to get [this effect (fiddle here)](https://jsfiddle.net/MasoomS/z1p5ttje/)

```
    .p_box {
        position: relative;
    }

    .p_box span {
        background-color: white;
        padding-right: 10px;
        display: table-cell;
        min-width: 200px;
    }
    .p_box:after {
        content:"";
        display: table-cell;
        width: 100%;
        height: 20px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        z-index: -1;
    }
```

You can use `min-width:` to set the min-width for `.p_box span` or you can remove min-width. If you remove the text will break by work. So I hope to use `min-width` is the proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for it?

```
.p_box:after {
    left: 90px;
}
```

Comment: That would be ok, but it does not take in consideration for text length. I mean if I would write something longer then Test, it would go over again.

Answer (score 0):

as i understand here is my try what you want

```css
        .p_box {
            position: relative;
        }

        .p_box span {
               background-color: white;
    padding: 5px;            //updated
    padding-right: 10px;     //updated
    line-height: 20px;       //updated
        }
        p.p_box:after{
           left:110px;      
        }
        .p_box:after {
            content:"";
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            height: 20px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            z-index: -1;
        }
```

```html
<body>
    <p class="p_box"><strong><span>Something:</span></strong></p>
</body>
```

checkout in the jsfiddle...

**[Updated DEMO code](https://jsfiddle.net/envLpanh/7/)**

---

**Updated code with Jquery** :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var text_block_width = $('.p_box strong span').outerWidth(true);
    debugger;
    console.log(text_block_width);
    $('p.p_box').append('<style>p.p_box:after{left:'+text_block_width+'px}</style>');
})
```

```css
        .p_box {
            position: relative;
            width;100%;
        }

        .p_box span {
               background-color: white;
    padding: 5px;            //updated
    padding-right: 10px;     //updated
    line-height: 20px;       //updated
        }
        .p_box:after {
            content:"";
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;          
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            height: 20px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            z-index: -1;
        }
```

```html
<body>
    <p class="p_box"><strong><span>hsdjfsdjfsdfjsdfjsdfjsdf blablallll:</span></strong></p>
</body>
```

DEMO working code

**[CHeck out code](https://jsfiddle.net/envLpanh/28/)**

Comment: Well it still hide left border. As you can see it does look like a box without one "wall". I need it that it would not hide any borders

Comment: @ Andrius then you need to make left positioning to the element which contains the border only that way you can achieve that

Comment: Updated answer would be kind of OK, but it runs in the same problem as with Hoomanhpc2 answer. If I would write longer text, it would mess things up. Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/envLpanh/8/. css somehow would need to know what `left` length should be by looking at text length or something. Then this approach would work.

Comment: @Andrius hey i think you can't set lyk this coz you are applying the border to the block containing nothing and you try to manage width with respect to the width of the block which is very.?? is it possible .? may be it can only be achieve by changing structure of html even i would love to know about this

Comment: @Andrius using finally achieved what you want please look it out

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this

[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/sanchit/br91nxjd/)

Following is the change is css code

```
.p_box:after {
content:"";
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 100px;
right: 0;
top: 0;
height: 20px;
border: 2px solid black;
z-index: -1;
```

}

Comment: Look at the problem I mentioned in Himesh Aadeshara answer. It is the same here.